# Filter a substring matching a pattern from an ansible variable and assign matched substring to another variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Let's say we have a long ansible string variable `mystr`. We have a regex pattern say `substr_pattern` and a substring matching this pattern is to be filtered out from `mystr` and to be assigned to another variable `substr`. There seems to be no obvious way to do this in ansible from the docs on [playbook_filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers) though it is simple to do this with `re` module in python itself.

There are 3 methods given in the ansible docs and none of them seems to solve my problem:

1. `match`: This filter returns true/false depending on whether the entire pattern matches the entire string but does not return matched group/substring.
2. `search`: Used to filter substr in a bigger string. But like `match`, only returns true/false and not matched group/substring that is needed here.
3. `regex_replace`: This is used to replace a matched pattern in a string with another string. But it's not clear how to register the substring/group corresponding to the matched pattern into a new variable.

Is there anything that I am missing? Or is this a missing feature in ansible?

Ansible Version: **2.1**

Example:

```
mystr: "This is the long string. With a url. http://example.org/12345"
pattern: "http:\/\/example.org\/(\d+)"
substr: 12345   # First matched group i.e. \\1
```

Summary: How to get the substring matching the `pattern` from `mystr` and register that to an ansible variable `substr`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you can modify the pattern, you could use the `regex_replace` filter and replace the whole string with only the matched digits.

```
mystr | regex_replace('^.*http:\/\/example.org\/(\d+).*?$', '\\1')
```

To assign the result to a new variable, you can use the `set_fact` module.

```
- set_fact:
    substr: "{{ mystr | regex_replace('^.*http:\/\/example.org\/(\d+).*?$', '\\1') }}"
```

Comment: This is brilliant and so simple. I wonder why this didn't come to my mind before posting! Would still hope ansible adds some filters that allow capturing matched groups directly. Your solution wasn't super obvious to me at first, since coming from python I was assuming there is a way to access matched groups directly like `match_obj.groups()[index]`